# Access array element within same array

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, programming-languages

Is this possible in PHP?

```
$a = array('first' => 'some value', 'second' => $a['first']);
```

Simply accessing an array element within another element from the same array.

Answer (score 3):

Not with this syntax, because at the time `$a['first']` is evaluated, `$a` is undefined.  This would work though:

```
$a = array();
$a['first'] = 'some value';
$a['second'] = $a['first'];
```